# How to avoid calling w3.org when creating an XSD Schema Validator in Grails

Tags: java, xml, grails, xsd

I use a service with the following code (redacted) to validate an XML against an XSD file. The xsd file is placed in `grails-app/conf/xsd` to be found by the classloader.

```
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource
import javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory
import javax.xml.validation.Schema
import static javax.xml.XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI

class MyService {

    Schema schema

    MyService() {
        def factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI),
            myXsd = this.class.classLoader.getResource("xsd/my.xsd")
        schema = factory.newSchema(myXsd)
    }

    void validate(String xml) {
        def validator = schema.newValidator()
        validator.validate(new StreamSource(new StringReader(xml)))
    }
}
```

It works, but the XSD is having some external resources fetched from w3.org.

With a network capture tool, I traced the following downloads:

```
http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/REC-xmldsig-core-20020212/xmldsig-core-schema.xsd
http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.dtd
http://www.w3.org/2001/datatypes.dtd
```

How can I cache local copies and avoid a roundtrip every time the service is created?

I tried the following:

```
MyService() {
    def factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI),
        resolver = new XMLCatalogResolver(),
        catalogs = [this.class.classLoader.getResource("xsd/catalog.xml").file],
        myXsd = this.class.classLoader.getResource("xsd/my.xsd")
    resolver.catalogList = catalogs
    factory.setResourceResolver resolver
    schema = factory.newSchema(myXsd)
}
```

Then I created an `xsd/catalog.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE catalog PUBLIC "-//OASIS/DTD Entity Resolution XML Catalog V1.0//EN"
          "http://www.oasis-open.org/committees/entity/release/1.0/catalog.dtd">
<catalog xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:entity:xmlns:xml:catalog" prefer="public">
    <uri name="http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/REC-xmldsig-core-20020212/xmldsig-core-schema.xsd"
         uri="xmldsig-core-schema.xsd"/>
    <uri name="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.dtd" uri="XMLSchema.dtd"/>
    <uri name="http://www.w3.org/2001/datatypes.dtd" uri="datatypes.dtd"/>
</catalog>
```

And I downloaded local copies of the XSD and DTD in the same directory as the catalog. But it's still not working, as evidenced by the startup times and by the network capture tool.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 1):

Solved.

I found [this page](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/faq-xcatalogs.html) that explains the format for such XML Catalogs.

For the XSD I needed to put its namespace (not its URL) into a `<uri name="..."` tag, while for the DTD I had to put its public id (the string after `PUBLIC`) into a `<public publicId="..."` tag:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE catalog
    PUBLIC "-//OASIS/DTD Entity Resolution XML Catalog V1.0//EN"
    "http://www.oasis-open.org/committees/entity/release/1.0/catalog.dtd">
<catalog xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:entity:xmlns:xml:catalog" prefer="public">
    <uri name="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" uri="xmldsig-core-schema.xsd"/>
    <public publicId="-//W3C//DTD XMLSchema 200102//EN" uri="XMLSchema.dtd"/>
    <public publicId="datatypes" uri="datatypes.dtd"/>
</catalog>
```

The rest was ok.